# Can an artifact be awarded to multiple characters on the same Marvel Heroes account?

Tags: marvel-heroes

Can a Mission Reward [artifact](http://marvelheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Artifacts) be awarded to multiple characters on the same account in Marvel Heroes?

I earned the [S.H.I.E.L.D. Motion Tracker](http://marvelheroes.wikia.com/wiki/S.H.I.E.L.D._Motion_Tracker) artifact with my first character and I really like the bonuses it gives.  Now that I've unlocked a second character, I'd like to use that artifact on the new character too.  Unfortunately, the artifact bound to my first character when it was equipped, so I can't just transfer it.

I've tried going back to the S.H.I.E.L.D Recon Post in Madripoor to talk to Agent Woo with the new character (which is how I got the artifact with the first character), but the artifact wasn't awarded a second time.  I also tried talking to Maria Hill at Avengers Tower, since she's the NPC who originally assigned the mission to find Agent Woo in Madripoor, but she doesn't assign that mission to the new character.  Is there any way to get a mission assigned or to get a reward artifact with a second character on the same account?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately as it stands, the mission rewards bind to your character and cannot be given to a new character.

Using the new character, try going to the S.H.I.E.L.D. waypoint, then selecting the mission that gave you the reward, after replaying the mission it should reward it again. It is not guaranteed however, as the game is still going through many changes while it is in early days. This is how I was able to gain some rewards a second time, but it doesn't work for everything, mainly for rewards given to you while you are in a new location. Rewards inside the Avengers Tower always seemed bugged to me.